# The ComposeView adapter does not work in a variant other than debugging

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

so the problem is i cannot see my preview of compose when set build variant different than debug.
Any ideas how to enable this on different build variants? I tried add `initWith(buildTypes.debug)` but nothing change.
[image]

Comment: I've tried switching to Release in my sample project, and Preview works fine. It may be related to your build variant setup in `build.gradle` or to your proguard file. Also I'd try adding `-keep class androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter` to the proguard file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the same issue. It's funny but you have to add

```
[buildTypeName]Implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
```

to app's level build.gradle to make it work for build type other than debug

```
//i.e. for [dev] build type:
devImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
```

Comment: Yes, that resolve the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting. I thought that's what [matchingFallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/8.0/com/android/build/api/dsl/BuildType#matchingFallbacks()) (`matchingFallbacks = ['debug', 'release']`) should cover, but it somehow doesn't work with the preview.

Answer (score 0):

for kotlin dsl:

As gradle won't recongize the custom build types, you need to add them in double qoutes like that:

```
  debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
 "myBuildTypeImplementation"("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
```